# Unable to match indices of two arrays when using `.unique` and `value_counts()`

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

While fetching data from data frame I am using one column and fetching unique values from that column using `.unique()` function and storing those values in `np.array`. Similarly for that column I am also fetching count of unique values using `.value_counts()` function and placing it into separate array. While doing so when I am getting two arrays I am unable to match their indices.

```
    x=np.array(df['Fruits'].unique())
    y=np.array(df['Fruits'].value_counts())
```

Actual result:
`array1=(['Apple','Mango','Orange'])  . array2=([10,4,17])` , where count of apple is 17 , count of mango is 10 and aount of orange is 4.                 Expected result `array1=(['Apple','Mango','Orange']) . array2=([17,10,4])`

Comment: does .unique perhaps sort alphabetically?

Answer (score 1):

Use group by instead

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Fruits': ['Mango']*15+['Apple']*10+['Orange']*5 })
adf = df.groupby(['Fruits']).size()
x = adf.index.values
y = adf.values
```

#### Why use group by

From Docs:

[`value_count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.value_counts.html?highlight=value_counts#pandas.Index.value_counts): The resulting object will be in descending order so that the first element is the most frequently-occurring element.

[`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.unique.html): Uniques are returned in order of appearance.

So the order is not consistent between the `value_count` and `unique`

Answer (score 0):

value_count will return a series of counts which are indexed by the value they are counting.

```
value_series = df['Fruits'].value_counts(sort=False)
x=np.array(value_series.index)
y=np.array(value_series.values)
```